# Segmentation error while inputting last array element

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to input an array of stings. The number of strings to be inputted is equal to the number of test cases. But when I try to input the last element, I get a segmentation error. Here is the code.

```
int main()
{
    int test_cases=0;
    scanf("%d",&test_cases);
    char t[100][test_cases];
    int length=0;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<test_cases;++i)
    {
        fgets(t[i],100,stdin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: typo `char t[100][test_cases];` --> `char t[test_cases][100];`

Comment: You cannot set `test_cases` to zero. This conclude `unknown size` error.

Comment: In addition of above useful comments, if the user enter string with the size more than the desired size, in the next loop `fgets` read the reminder characters from the previous loop!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about your code:

```
scanf("%d",&test_cases);
char t[100][test_cases];
```

This declares a char array that can hold 100 entries, each is `test_cases` long. Then in your loop:

```
for(i=0;i<test_cases;++i)
{
    fgets(t[i],100,stdin);
}
```

See how `fgets` is declared:

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

You are writing to each of your entries an input that can be 100 bytes long. Earlier you've declared it to be `test_cases` long. Suppose that your `test_cases` is equal to 3 and you've added code to print out chars that you've stored:

```
for(i=0;i<test_cases;++i)
{
    printf("%s\n", t[i]);
}
```

Then you type in following sequence:

```
abc
def
```

Whoops, you wanted to type in third string, but loop terminated. Your output is

```
abcdef
def
```

What happened? Firstly, if you have hit enter while `scanf`ing `test_cases` variable, there's a dangling newline character on stdin and it is read by fgets. Then, fgets reads in `abc` to t[1], but the null character that terminates your string is stored on next row. That's because multi dimensional arrays are stored contiguously in memory. Later, `def` is read and `\0` is lost. You wanted to print out your rows with `printf` function. `printf` keeps on printing chars until it meets `\0` character. `def`'s termination character is stored on next row, hence printf terminates on it. Second input is printed properly. 
At the moment, `t` array looks like:

```
t[0]   -   \n
t[1]   -   abc
t[2]   -   def
t[3]   -   \0

/* in memory: */
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| \n  |     |     |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |  f  | \0  |     |     | 
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+ . . .
|_________________|_________________|_________________|_________________|
       t[0]              t[1]              t[2]              t[3]
```

Luckily you've got more rows to store \0.

So you have a typo. You probably meant to declare a char array, that can hold `test_cases` entries, each 100 bytes long, which is

```
char t[test_cases][100]
```

However, you still would lost one row of your array, since `fgets` would stop on reading that dangling newline character (there's 100 bytes unused!). To deal with that, after scanf you can call a `getchar()` function, or press ctrl+d key combination (which results in sending EOF). Scanf needs to know that you're done with specyfing `test_cases`. And also remember to have additional space for \0 terminating character.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful... But may I know why I get that '\n' character as 1st element of the array?

Answer (score 2):

The array dimension is wrong. Use

```
char t[test_cases][100];
```

instead

```
char t[100][test_cases];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following code to read the whole strings.

```
int test_cases;
char tmp[1];
scanf("%d", &test_cases);
gets(tmp);
char *t[100];
int length = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i<test_cases; i++)
{
    t[i] = (char*)malloc(test_cases);
    gets(t[i]);
}
```

Comment: -1, `gets` is dangerous in C89, deprecated in C99, and forbidden in C11, and don't cast malloc ...